# How to bind to a form's ajax:success in typescript with JQuery/Rails UJS

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, typescript

I'm using Rails 6, webpacker, and ts-loader. I have @types/jquery installed. I have this code.

```
interface PDFSave {
  url: string;
}

interface AjaxSuccessEvent {
  detail: [PDFSave, any, any];
}

$(() => {
  const setup = ($container: JQuery<HTMLElement>) => {
    $container
    .on('ajax:success', (e: AjaxSuccessEvent) => {
      const [data] = e.detail;
      // here I want to use the PDFSave data...
    })
  };

  const $container = $('form.pdf-save-form');
  setup($container);
});
```

Typescript says this:

[tsl] ERROR in /Users/(me)/work/(rails app folder)/app/javascript/(relevant file).ts(12,9)
TS2769: No overload matches this call.
The last overload gave the following error.
Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'TypeEventHandlers<HTMLElement, (e: AjaxSuccessEvent) => void, HTMLElement, HTMLElement>'.

I know Rails UJS returns the parsed json of the ajax call as the first element of a 3-tuple, in the detail property of the event. I'm returning json of {url: "http://some/place"} from the ajax call on the server side.

My question is how do I elegantly get this concept to pass with Typescript, without a compiler error.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to change the event type to fit one of the jquery `on(...)` overloads, and then downcast to conform to my special event type. Had to extend JQueryEventObject, too.

```
interface PDFSave {
  url: string;
}

interface AjaxSuccessEvent extends JQueryEventObject {
  detail: [PDFSave, any, any];
}

$(() => {
  const setup = ($container: JQuery<HTMLElement>) => {
    $container
    .on('ajax:success', (e: JQueryEventObject) => {
      const [data] = (e as AjaxSuccessEvent).detail;
      // can use PDFSave data...
    })
  };

  const $container = $('form.pdf-save-form');
  setup($container);
});
```